# data scraping on discord using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, discord

I'm currently trying to learn web **scraping** and decided to **scrape** some discord data. Code follows:

```
import requests
import json

def retrieve_messages(channelid):
    num=0
    headers = {
        'authorization': 'here we enter the authorization code'
    }
    r = requests.get(
        f'https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{channelid}/messages?limit=100',headers=headers
        )
    jsonn = json.loads(r.text)
    for value in jsonn:
        print(value['content'], '\n')
        num=num+1
    print('number of messages we collected is',num)

retrieve_messages('server id goes here')
```

The problem: when I tried changing the limit here `messages?limit=100` apparently it only accepts numbers between 0 and 100, meaning that the maximum number of messages I can get is 100. I tried changing this number to 900, for example, to scrape more messages. But then I get the error `TypeError: string indices must be integers`.

Any ideas on how I could get, possibly, all the messages in a channel?

Thank you very much for reading!

Comment: would you mind telling how you generated the token. I'm generating the token using OAAUTH as per this stackoverflow .. still getting 401 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72778406/read-my-discord-channel-historical-messages-from-discord

Answer (score 8):

APIs that return a bunch of records are almost always limited to some number of items.
Otherwise, if a large quantity of items is requested, the API may fail due to being out of memory.

For that purpose, most APIs implement pagination using `limit`, `before` and `after` parameters where:

- `limit`: tells you how many messages to fetch
- `before`: get messages before this message ID
- `after`: get messages after this message ID

Discord API is no exception as the [documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#get-channel-messages) tells us.
Here's how you do it:

First, you will need to query the data multiple times.
For that, you can use a while loop.
Make sure to add an if the condition that will prevent the loop from running indefinitely - I added a check whether there are any messages left.

```py
    while True:
        # ... requests code
        jsonn = json.loads(r.text)
        if len(jsonn) == 0:
            break
        
        for value in jsonn:
            print(value['content'], '\n')
            num=num+1
```

Define a variable that has the last message that you fetched and save the last message id that you already printed

```py
        
def retrieve_messages(channelid):
    last_message_id = None

    while True:
        # ...
        
        for value in jsonn:
            print(value['content'], '\n')
            last_message_id = value['id']
            num=num+1
```

Now on the first run the last_message_id is None, and on subsequent requests it has the last message you printed.

Use that to build your query

```py
    while True:
        query_parameters = f'limit={limit}'
        if last_message_id is not None:
            query_parameters += f'&before={last_message_id}'

        r = requests.get(
            f'https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{channelid}/messages?{query_parameters}',headers=headers
            )
        
        # ...
```

Note: discord servers give you the latest message first, so you have to use the `before` parameter

Here's a fully working example of your code

```py
import requests
import json

def retrieve_messages(channelid):
    num = 0
    limit = 10

    headers = {
        'authorization': 'auth header here'
    }

    last_message_id = None

    while True:
        query_parameters = f'limit={limit}'
        if last_message_id is not None:
            query_parameters += f'&before={last_message_id}'

        r = requests.get(
            f'https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{channelid}/messages?{query_parameters}',headers=headers
            )
        jsonn = json.loads(r.text)
        if len(jsonn) == 0:
            break

        for value in jsonn:
            print(value['content'], '\n')
            last_message_id = value['id']
            num=num+1

    print('number of messages we collected is',num)

retrieve_messages('server id here')
```

Answer (score 3):

To answer this question, we must look at the discord API. Googling "discord api get messages" gets us the developer reference for the discord API. The particular endpoint you are using is documented here:

https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#get-channel-messages

The limit is documented here, along with the `around`, `before`, and `after` parameters. Using one of these parameters (most likely `after`) we can paginate the results.

In pseudocode, it would look something like this:

```
offset = 0
limit = 100
all_messages=[]
while True:
    r = requests.get(
        f'https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{channelid}/messages?limit={limit}&after={offset}',headers=headers
        )
    all_messages.append(extract messages from response)
    if (number of responses < limit):
        break # We have reached the end of all the messages, exit the loop
    else:
        offset += limit
```

By the way, you will probably want to `print(r.text)` right after the response comes in so you can see what the response looks like. It will save a lot of confusion.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Just added this piece to the code. Just a question, in ```(extract messages from response)``` what should I put here? Would it be r.text? I'm getting ```SyntaxError: invalid syntax``` the way it is written

Comment: Based on what you have written, it looks like `value` (from your for loop) would correspond to a single message?

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying! To be honest I don't understand completely what is happening there. I'm quite new to python, but I will try to figure it out

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution. Feedback is welcome as I'm newish to Python. Kindly provide me w/ credit/good-luck if using this. Thank you =)

```
import requests

CHANNELID = 'REPLACE_ME'
HEADERS = {'authorization': 'REPLACE_ME'}
LIMIT=100
all_messages = []

r = requests.get(f'https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{CHANNELID}/messages?limit={LIMIT}',headers=HEADERS)
all_messages.extend(r.json())

print(f'len(r.json()) is {len(r.json())}','\n')

while len(r.json()) == LIMIT:
    last_message_id = r.json()[-1].get('id')
    r = requests.get(f'https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{CHANNELID}/messages?limit={LIMIT}&before={last_message_id}',headers=HEADERS)
    all_messages.extend(r.json())
    print(f'len(r.json()) is {len(r.json())} and last_message_id is {last_message_id} and len(all_messages) is {len(all_messages)}')
```